# OpenCV 3.4: the result of resize in CPU and CUDA are not match in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, image-resizing

I am using OpenCV with C++ to resize a frame

Following is the code that I use in **CPU**

```
cv::resize(in_mat, out_mat, out_mat.size(), 0, 0, cv::INTER_LINEAR);
```

The code for **CUDA** is as follows

```
cv::cuda::resize(dev_in_mat, dev_out_mat, dev_out_mat.size(), 0, 0, cv::INTER_LINEAR, stream);
```

The issue is, I get different outputs for both. Why does that happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known problem in OpenCV.
See the issue report [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/4728)

There seems being two versions currently, one with npp (legacy) and another one without it (newer):

[legacy version](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/9735ec666c92f7853fd7f20468e7ac701d3a2df0/modules/cudalegacy/src/cuda/NPP_staging.cu#L2360)
and
[newer version](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/9735ec666c92f7853fd7f20468e7ac701d3a2df0/modules/cudawarping/src/cuda/resize.cu)

It also seems that this issue is an active one and has been bumped up to **priority:normal** meaning we should see a fix soon, just follow that thread and you'll be fine!

Hope I helped, this was my first post on SO :D

Edit:

To build without NPP one must build a branch separate to the master branch in OpenCV:

See the **newer version** [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tree/9735ec666c92f7853fd7f20468e7ac701d3a2df0)

1. Git clone / Download as Zip
2. Follow instructions on page for building OpenCV

If reinstalling opencv-contrib from this branch does not fix it, then its a bug in opencv and you've got to wait util someone updates it [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/4728)

Comment: So, do you know how can I build without the npp? I didn't find any option like WITHOUT_NPP.
It's my first post too, haha :)

Comment: Thanks! I'm using v3.4.0, and I found the resize implementation is in ```modules/cudawarping```, but not in ```modules/cudalegacy```, is it the newer or the legacy?